# Accessing react-router parameters in server side rendering initial data retrieval

Tags: express, reactjs, redux, react-router, universal

I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious. FWIW, I'm using React, Redux, React-Router, React-Router-Redux bindings and Express for the server side.

I'm working on my first universal react application and everything for the most part is working great. I have an action, "fetchData" that runs on the server and resolves a promise before initially rendering the page, and then the client side checks whether it needs to fetch data.

All of this is working just as I want.

However, I'm running into a bit of trouble when I need to access a parameter in the router on the server before rendering the page.

An example would be:

```
http://myapp.com/update/:updateid
```

How do I properly access the updateid parameter in my initial fetchData action? I've done so successfully on the client side using the context object -- but I am a bit confused on where to do so here.

I can see it in renderProps passed to my RouterContext, I just don't know how to grab it. Do I do it using React-Router or do something in express?

(I managed to temporarily solve it by doing the following code, but I KNOW this is really terrible, hence why I am wanting to do it properly)

```
// Grab the requested user from the router / url
const pathname = state.getIn(['routing', 'locationBeforeTransitions', 'pathname']);

// Strip out /update/ from the route string
const updatePath = '/update/';
let pathnameWithoutTrailing = pathname;
if (pathname.endsWith('/') || pathname.endsWith('#') || pathname.endsWith('?')) {
  pathnameWithoutTrailing = pathname.slice(0, -1);
}
requestedUpdate = pathnameWithoutTrailing.substr(updatePath.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. You can access the updateId in your container by using this.props.params.updateId. You'll need to pass the updateId to your fetchData action as a parameter. Like so:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchData(this.props.params.updateId))
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to have the server run the API call and grab the data before it ever renders. Having the server render the page, then having the client stuff send the info to the server doesn't really seem to make sense, because the server should be able to access the parameters before the client even knows about it.

The example code I posted works, as it properly sends the API request off before the page gets rendered and is available on first load, but I know there has to be a better way to access the router props on the server.

Comment: If I console.log renderProps in my server code, I can see the part I want to use as part of it like so:



    { path: 'update/:updateid', getComponent: [Function: getComponent] } ],
  params: { updateid: 'jor74n6lsgWHk' },



So basically, I want to use that param on a server side action without having to go and get it from the client first